# Can't access a session cookie with a domain and path

Tags: javascript, session-cookies

I want to know : why i can't access this session cookie that has a domain and path ?

Is there a solution ?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to do to access this cookie?

Comment: if the cookie is HTTP-only, you can not read it, only the issuing server can access it

Comment: @JamesWhiteley i colored the "document.cookie" in the console

Comment: @JamesWhiteley it seems that it is an HTTP-Only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't shown all the data from the cookie inspector, but most session cookies are marked [`httpOnly`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies) which explicitly sets them to be inaccessible to client-side JavaScript.

There is almost never a good reason for client-side JS to access a cookie identifier, so marking them as httpOnly prevents an XSS attack from passing the session ID to an attacker (which would make it much easier to hijack the session).